# Javascript variable scope inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm using `formidable` ([github](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable%20%22github%29)) and I'm not sure about the scope of some variables inside the callbacks.
Part of my code is:

```
UploadHandler.prototype.upload = function(req, res){
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var id = query['X-Progress-ID'];

    self.uploads.add(id);

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        self.uploads.remove(id);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
        return res.end('upload received');
    });

    ...

}
```

My question is, what will be the value of `id` inside the callback of `parse`? Also, will that code work as expected if more than 1 person is uploading a file? (As in, will `id` change it's value for both the first and the second person if they're both using the uploader at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is what you defined and yes, it will work if there's more than one call to `upload` : the `id` variable is local to the invocation of the `upload` function. The scope here is the function call which forms what's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Here's a simplified version of your code :

```
function upload(i){
   var id=i; // id is local to the invocation of upload
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log(id) }, 100*i);
}
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    upload(i);
}
```

It logs `0, 1, 2`.